# How can I escape commas within double quotes during a replace?

Tags: powershell, escaping

I am using PowerShell to iterate over a specified list of files, using `-replace` to increment a version string within each and the version string contains commas. For example:

```
VERSION 6,21,0,0
```

needs to become:

```
VERSION 7,1,0,0
```

Here is what I'm doing:

```
ForEach-Object -InputObject $Files -Process {
    foreach ($str in $_) {
        (Get-Content -Path $str) | ForEach {
            $_ -replace "VERSION \d+,\d+,0,0","VERSION $MAJOR,$MINOR,0,0"
        } | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 $str
    }
```

which is *mostly* working, except the commas are being replaced by dots.

```
VERSION 6,21,0,0
```

becomes:

```
VERSION 7.1.0.0
```

I understand the need for double quotes so `$MAJOR` and `$MINOR` are evaluated, but when I do that the commas are handled as shown above. Using the backtick to escape the commas has no effect on the output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can't reproduce. `,` isn't a special character in either regular expressions or replacement strings, so it should remain untouched. You can try escaping the commas with backticks, though: ``"VERSION $MAJOR`,$MINOR`,0`,0"``

Comment: Fun puzzle. What if you have some culture conversion happening? You're in Texas, and I think Mexico tends to use comma instead of dot for decimal points. Or what if you have actual version types? `$v = New-Object version(7,1); "$v"` will have a comma in the creation and a dot in the output string. Or what if you're reading/writing different files compared to what you expect and they already have "7.1.0.0" in and the replace is doing nothing? Or they are commas, but are at the very lowest pixel line of your terminal and you can't see the descender? None apply to your code, or are convincing...